# Drupal prevent unauthorized access

Tags: drupal

How to prevent unauthorized url access in drupal?

I already tried 'access arguments' => array('access administration pages') but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Its clearly given in the `Drupal` documentation on how to use the `Access Arguments`.This example is as per `Drupal` documentation,just to make it more clear for you on how to use this.

```
$items['test/myPage'] = array(
    'title' => 'myPage',
    'description' => 'Welcome',
    'page callback' => 'mypage_info',
    'access arguments' => array('Anyone can access this'),
  );
```

//Define user permissions.

```
function hook_perm() {
        return array('Anyone can access this');
}
```

Now go to the `permissions page [Administer --> User Management -->Permissions)`, there you can see a list of strings you used for `access arguments`.You could find the `access argument` named 'Anyone can access this' in your corresponding `module`.Give the necessary `permission` for your `required user roles`.

You could get more information on the following links

https://drupal.org/node/553368

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_perm/6